# Converting PyQt5 app into Android Apk using Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have made many Kivy or KivyMD apps and also converted it into Android and it works just fine.

Now, I want to know that if there's a simple way to convert a PyQt5 app into Android Apk by using terminal (just like buildozer in kivy).

Comment: PyQt does not provide that capability

Comment: Okay then, any other GUI Framework which provide that capability?

Comment: Answer: kivy....